# Xcode ligatures

Tags: fonts, xcode15, ligature

I am currently using Xcode 15 with JetBrains mono font.
How can I disable font ligatures?

All options in `Edit` -> `Format` -> `Font` -> `Ligatures` are disabled.
And none of `typography` section on `Pref` -> `Themes` -> `Source editor` options work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found no way to disable font ligature, but `JetBrains Mono` has its own version without ligatures called `JetBrains Mono NL`